# Vertices and indices of a tesseract before and after projection

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

how to define the vertices and indices of a tesseract  before and after projection into 3D ,is the way in which vertices are connected to form lines " Wireframe " in 4D remains the same after projection.

I'm learning graphics programming and my mathematical understanding isn't that much.

Comment: If you are only concerned about the vertices and edges that connect the adjacent ones in 4D, those connections (of labelled vertices) remain "the same" when projected into 3D.  Of course there are many projections possible, and in a rare case two edges may happen to cross (intersect) at a point other than a vertex in 3D.  You can probably select a projection to avoid this, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we think of a projection as a continuous mapping from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  There are many kinds of projections used in computer graphics, but the computations generally represent continuous functions, sometimes affine or even linear.

In any case continuous linear mappings (which is a bit redundant; all finite dimensional linear maps are continuous) preserve the connectedness of vertices by their edges (linearity or affineness implying straight line segments in 4D go over to straight line segments in 3D).

As far as setting up a tesseract in 4D, the standard "unit" tesseract would be sixteen vertices with four 0,1 coordinates and edges between any pair of points whose coordinates are the same in all but one coordinate.  You can scale this up to a larger size if that tesseract is too small for graphic display.  The vertex labelling might conveniently be done with numbers 0-15 by identifying a binary representation with their coordinates.

Comment: ,yes it does, thanks.